# $wpdb->prepare with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: wpdb, sql, duplicates

I just took [this code](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Examples_10) from $wpdb Codex page, and modified my existing Insert query:

```
$table = $wpdb->prefix . 'user_req';

$post_id = explode('_', $_POST['post_id']);
$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
$wpdb->insert( 
        $table,
        array(
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'post_id' => $post_id[1]
        ),
        array( 
            '%d',
            '%d'
        )
    );
```

into:

```
$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( 
            "
                INSERT INTO {$wpdb->prefix}user_req
                ( user_id, post_id )
                VALUES ( %d, %d )
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                user_id = VALUES(user_id), post_id = VALUES(post_id)
            ", 
            $user_id, 
            $post_id[1]
        ) );
```

Because I need to **prevent the duplicate entries** entering into the database. But still the duplicate entries are entering into the db while the insert query is functioning properly. To add the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` portion, I followed the [s_ha_dum's Answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/128390/22728) on another thread.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you actually have a duplicate key here? What is the structure of user_req and what are the keys and indexes?

Comment: @Otto: May be you directed me on the actual matter. Actually I want to prevent entering duplicate `post_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's my fault. Got the solution after @Otto's comment:

> Do you actually have a duplicate key here? What is the structure of
> user_req and what are the keys and indexes?

Here's how my SQL query should be:

```
INSERT INTO {$wpdb->prefix}user_req
                ( user_id, post_id )
                VALUES ( %d, %d )
                WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                  SELECT * FROM
                  {$wpdb->prefix}user_req.user_id = user_id
                  AND
                  {$wpdb->prefix}user_req.post_id = post_id
                )
```

Fixed now. Thanks to Otto.

### UPDATE

Though I said, it's solved, but actually, it's not. The code somehow was not working and not even inserting data ([Details here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23440808/1743124)). So with the knowledge I had from the others, and with assistance of my colleague Mr. Ariful Haque, I did it with two different but interlocking queries:

```
    $alreadyGot = $wpdb->get_results(
                        "SELECT
                        COUNT(*) AS TOTALCOUNT
                        FROM {$table}
                        WHERE ( user_id = $user_id AND post_id = $post_id[1] )
                            AND ( order_id = '' )"
                    );

    $count = $alreadyGot[0]->TOTALCOUNT; //if there's any duplicate, it'd return 1

    // if the count return 1, do nothing, but else insert the data
    if( $count > 0 ) {
        //do nothing
    } else {
        $wpdb->insert( 
            $table,
            array(
                'user_id' => $user_id,
                'post_id' => $post_id[1]
            )
        );
    }
```

Comment: so on duplicate key actually won't work with wpdb? For instance I have a query "INSERT INTO my_locations (location_id,address,lat,lng) VALUES (%d,%s,%f,%f) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE address = %s, lat = %f, lng = %f"; and when using prepare() it returns false. Will I really have to rewrite the query somehow?

Comment: We better ask a different question, if this one doesn't solve your issue.